# How to automatically renew a subscription package when a user reaches the usage limit using Stripe or another payment platform?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, payment, subscription

I have a website with packages (abcd), and users can choose to subscribe to one of these packages. The packages have no expiration date but have a limit on usage. When a user reaches the usage limit, I want to automatically renew their package without requiring any manual action from the user.

In my implementation, I have integrated Stripe as the payment platform on my website and created subscription packages with usage limits. I have implemented the functionality to track and monitor the user's usage and their respective package limits.

What I have tried:

```
Integrated Stripe: I have successfully integrated Stripe into my website, allowing users to make payments and manage their subscriptions.

Created Subscription Packages: I have created different subscription packages (abcd) using the Stripe dashboard, specifying the pricing and usage limits for each package.

Usage Tracking: I have implemented a mechanism to track and monitor the user's usage on my website. This includes updating and storing the user's current usage in a database.
```

What I was expecting:

I was expecting to automatically renew the user's subscription package when they reach the usage limit associated with their current package. This renewal process should occur without requiring any manual action from the user.

However, I am unsure about how to implement the automatic renewal functionality using Stripe or any other payment platform. I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this automated renewal process based on the user's usage limit.

Comment: I have come up with a solution. Add a balance field for users where they can deposit any amount into their account. These deposited amounts will be converted into a balance within my website. Then, I can use this balance to automatically renew the subscription once the usage limit is reached.